# Basic Ubuntu configuration

Tags: installation

I've installed Ubuntu onto a new machine and I haven't got a clue where to start. How to add a wireless network, add printers and how to access the command prompt?

This is the 1st time out of my Windows comfort zone.

Answer (score 2):

Hi welcome to ask ubuntu!

It may be the best when you start here: [Ubuntu: An absolute beginners guide](http://www.makeuseof.com/pages/ubuntu-an-absolute-beginners-guide#chapter-6). There you will see the dash, the panel and the applications explained and how to go further steps.

Or for more elaboraton, I can recommend the [Ubuntu Manual Project](http://ubuntu-manual.org/). This is also available in many languages.

May be this community can become your new comfort zone =)